# difference between ..cx and sjoin in geopandas for filtering by bounding box?

Tags: gis, geopandas

I have a set of candidate points and a set of reference points in lon/lat coordinate space. I have created a bounding box around each of my candidate points, and I would like to check the reference points to see what reference points fall within each box.

What is the advantage of using a geopandas spatial join over something like slicing the geopandas frame with .cx[lon1:lon2, lat1:lat2] ? IS there a difference?

Comment: Spatial join will likely be faster. It is using a spatial index and the query is done in C, while `.cx` is non-indexed spatial operation, which can be relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

A key difference between these two is what parameters they take.

According to the [docs](https://geopandas.org/indexing.html), the cx method performs coordinate based indexing, it takes slices of coordinate ranges.
The spatial join ([docs](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html)) takes two GeoDataFrames.

In my limited testing, the cx method is ~6x faster than spatial join.